# If statements in 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

When I am trying to run this code it shows java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please help me to fix this code.

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    final int N, S;

    System.out.print("Input No of Students : ");
    N = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("No of Subject : ");
    S = input.nextInt();

    int[][] st = new int[N][S];
    int[] stNo = new int[N];
    int[] stMax = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        stNo[i] = r.nextInt(10000);
        for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
            st[i][j] = r.nextInt(101);
        }
    }

    // Find max Value of marks of a Student
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
            if (st[i][j] > st[i][j + 1]) {
                stMax[i] = st[i][j + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    // Display marks
    // Dispaly Column names
    System.out.print("stNo\t");
    for (int i = 1; i < S + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("Sub " + i + "\t");
    }
    System.out.print("Max");

    // Print Values
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.print(stNo[i] + "\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
            System.out.print(st[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print(stMax[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The error is

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: (here shows the input for "S")
at pack1.Example.main(Example.java:31)
```

As I am a new to coding I can not fix this. Please help me to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: First you need to learn how to identify the line in error.

Comment: You should include the entire stack trace (the exception) in the question, and indicate the applicable lines, since we can't instantly see lines numbers from just looking at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error means you exceed the boundaries of the array. In your case, st has S colomns and you tried to reach the `S+1`-th element (index `S`).

`st[i][j + 1]` => when `j == S-1` (the end of the loop), you do an out of bounds.

Now, as your comment say, you're looking for the max value. Then the code should be:

```
    stMax[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
        if (st[i][j] > stMax[i]) {
            stMax[i] = st[i][j];
        }
    }
```

What your code is doing is comparing the current value to the next one. And every time the next value is greater than the current one, you update stMax[i]. This does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the exception:

```
 stMax[i] = st[i][j + 1];
```

You are iterating j to the end of the array, and always looking for the next element. So when j reaches the end of the array it is still looking for one more index, hence the outOfBoundsException.